# OnClick() event is not working in JavaScript for dynamic button in my code

Tags: javascript, html

I have added a dynamic buttons inside for loop on webpage using JavaScript  and assigned a unique id to each button. I wants to assign onclick() event Listener to each button but this function is not being assigned to any of dynamic buttons. Kindly help me resolving this. Thank You.

> `myfunction()`is working but `myfunction1()` has some problem. I cannot see onclick event in its dynamically HTML. [image: HTML view]

There are JS file. data.js contains arrays of objects and other contains function which access the data.

```js
// function.js
function chargerArticles() {

  var myShoppingCart = [];



  var articles = document.getElementById("content");
  for (var i = 0; i < catalogArray.length; i++) {


    //Product div
    var article = document.createElement("div");
    article.setAttribute("class", "aa");
    //Unique id
    article.id = i + "-article";

      //Product Name
    var articleName = document.createElement("h4");
    articleName.setAttribute("class", "aa-product-title");
    var articleNameLink=  document.createElement('a');
    articleNameLink.setAttribute('href',"#");
    articleNameLink.innerText = catalogArray[i].name;
    articleName.appendChild(articleNameLink);

    article.appendChild(articleName);

    //Command Input Area
    var zoneCmd = document.createElement("div");

    var inputCmd = document.createElement("input");

    //Button of add to cart
    var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    button.setAttribute("class", "Btn hvr-underline-btn");
    button.innerHTML = " ADD";

    //Button unique id
    button.id = i + "-cmd";

    //not working
    button.addEventListener("click", myFunction1);

    function myFunction1() {
      var item = this.getAttribute("id");
      var pos = item.substring(0, 1);
      document.getElementById("1235").innerHTML = "Hello World";
      addToCart(pos);
    }

    //working
    document.getElementById("1234").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("1234").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
    }


    zoneCmd.appendChild(button); //child 2
    //zoneCmd child of article element
    article.appendChild(zoneCmd);



    //finally article as a child of articles 
    articles.appendChild(article);
  }
}

function searchInCart(name) //T-Shirt
{
  myShoppingCart = myCartArray;
  var name1 = name;
  var stop = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myShoppingCart.length && stop == 0; i++) {
    if (myShoppingCart[i].name == name1) {
      stop = 1;
      // console.log("Hello wooooorld!");
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

}

function addToCart(pos) {

  if (searchInCart(catalogArray[pos].name)) {
    alert("Already Exist!"); // display string message

  } else {
    var ident = pos + "-qte";
    var quatity = document.getElementById("ident").value;
    if (quatity > 0) {
      var articleCmd = {}; //array of  objects
      articleCmd.name = catalogArray[pos].name;
      articleCmd.price = catalogArray[pos].price;
      articleCmd.qte = quatity;
      articleCmd.priceTotal = articleCmd.price * articleCmd.qte;
      myCartArray.push(articleCmd);

    } else {
      // alert
    }
  }

}


//data.js

// data.js
var catalogArray = [{
    code: 100,
    name: "T Shirt c100",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known as",
    price: 150,
    image: "./images/img100.jpg"
  },
  {
    code: 101,
    name: "T Shirt c101",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known as",
    price: 250,
    image: "./images/img101.jpg"
  },

];



var myCartArray = [{
    name: "T Shirt c100",
    price: 150,
    qte: 2,
    TotalPrice: 150,
  }

];
```

Comment: WHY do you have the function INSIDE the loop. That is very very inefficient. Also delegate instead

Comment: you might need to add event delegations to the dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not add a function in a loop
2. Delegate

Have a look here. There are MANY issues, I have addressed a few of them

You MAY want to do

```
button.setAttribute("data-code",item.code);
```

instead of

```
button.id = i + "-cmd";
```

```js
// function.js

const content = document.getElementById("content");

content.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target,  // the element clicked
    id = tgt.id; // the ID of the element
  if (id.indexOf("-cmd") !=-1) { // is that element one of our buttons?
   // get the name of the article from the button - this could also be a data attibute
    var pos = id.split("-")[1]; 
    addToCart(pos);
  }  
})

function chargerArticles() {

  const myShoppingCart = catalogArray.map(function(item, i) {
    //Product div
    var article = document.createElement("div");
    article.setAttribute("class", "aa");
    //Unique id
    article.id = i + "-article";
    // here would be a good place to add item.name or something
    //Command Input Area
    var zoneCmd = document.createElement("div");
    var inputCmd = document.createElement("input");
    //Button of add to cart
    var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    button.setAttribute("class", "Btn hvr-underline-btn");
    button.innerHTML = " ADD";
    //Button unique id
    button.id = i + "-cmd";

    zoneCmd.appendChild(button); //child 2
    //zoneCmd child of article element
    article.appendChild(zoneCmd);
    //finally article as a child of articles 
    articles.appendChild(article);
    content.appendChild(articles) // ???
  })
}

function searchInCart(name) {
  return myCartArray.filter(function(x) {
    return x.name === name
  })[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your efforts for helping me out.  can you please explain `const tgt = e.target, id = tgt.id;`   I am  beginner  in JS and I don't have thorough understanding of code.

Comment: when you delegate - like I delegate from content, the (e) is the event passed. The event.target is the button or whatever else is clicked in the content container. I get the ID from the target to test if it is one that contains the -cmd your buttons contain.

Comment: what am I supposed to write dynamic button's id in place of  e.target?

Comment: No. The tgt = e.target gets what was clicked. Then I test tgt.id to see if it contains ".....-cmd"

Comment: PS: Using just the index as an article ID is possibly not very scalable - perhaps use the  `code`

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurred because you defined `myfunction1` dynamically. In other words, this element wasn't defined during the initial rendering of the page.

You can fix it by using event delegation. Here is how:

Instead of defining the callback on the element, define it for all children of the **PARENT** element that have the matching css class. For example:

```
     $( ".btnContainer .btn" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
     console.log("clicked");

    });
```

where:

```
 <div class='btnContainer'>
 </div>
```

Now when you add buttons with (class name `btn`) dynamically as children of `btnContainer`, they will still get access to the click handler, because the event handler isn't bound to the element `btn`, but to it's **parent**, hence when the click event is fired, the parent **delegates** the event to all it's children with the matching class(es)!

Comment: Thank you. I get your point but can you help fixing this in my code using delegation. I am v beginner to JS so I am not getting where and to add it in my code as I have someother data to display in page I skipped in question. I am updating it for your reference